# Disabled jQuery contextMenu after a mouseup-event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contextmenu

When using a custom text-selection function in jQuery, my contextMenu event gets disabled.

Minimal working example, with javascript and the html file (the amount of javascript is less the it looks):

```js
var markFeature = {
    
    getSelected: function(){
 var t = '';
 if(window.getSelection)
     t = window.getSelection();
 else if(document.getSelection)
     t = document.getSelection();
 else if(document.selection)
     t = document.selection.creatRange().text;
 return t;
    },
    
    applyHighlight: function(){
 var st = markFeature.getSelected();
 if(st!='')
    {
     var str1 = '<span style="background-color:#00E000">';
     var replacement = str1.concat(st,"</span>");
     var _st = new RegExp(st, "g");
     var replaced = $("body").html().replace(_st, replacement);
     $("body").html(replaced);
 }
    },

    register_contextMenu: function(){
 //markFeature.addCSS();
 $.contextMenu({
     selector: '*',
     items: {
  "item1": {name: "item-1"},
  "item2": {name:"item-2"},
     }
 });
    },
           
    init: function(){
 $(document).bind("mouseup", markFeature.applyHighlight);
    }

};
$(document).ready(markFeature.register_contextMenu);
$(document).ready(markFeature.init);
```

```html
<link href="http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/src/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/src/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>

<strong>Right-Click ME!</strong>
```

Please ignore a little bug: sometimes it adds text after a selection.

So my problem is: after a selection I am unable to use the contextMenu.

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if you feel it answers your question. You are under no obligation, however.

Answer (score 0):

The RegEx searches the body tag and all the HTML within the body tag. The HTML for the context menu is added by the contextMenu JS within the body tag so it gets altered and breaks.

I removed `getSelected` and the RegEx. I replaced these with an adapted [example](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule) from [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/):

```
<script src="http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/currentrelease/rangy-core.js"></script>
<script src="http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/currentrelease/rangy-cssclassapplier.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .highLight {
    background-color: #00E000;
  }
</style>
<script>
  var cssApplier, markFeature;

  window.onload = function() {
    rangy.init();
    cssApplier = rangy.createCssClassApplier("highLight", {
      normalize: true
    });
  };

  $(this).on("mouseup", function() {
    cssApplier.applyToSelection();
  });

  markFeature = {
    register_contextMenu: function() {
      $.contextMenu({
        selector: "*",
        items: {
          item1: {
            name: "item-1"
          },
          item2: {
            name: "item-2"
          }
        }
      });
    },
    init: function() {
      $(document).bind("mouseup", markFeature.applyHighlight);
    }
  };

  $(document).ready(markFeature.register_contextMenu);

  $(document).ready(markFeature.init);
</script>
```

Comment: How is the javascript of the contextMenu withing the body tag?

Comment: Furthermore, this feature needs to work for generic webpages. Hence we do not have a predefined div to search for, just the body of the webpage, which will consist of text.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer based on your feedback.